# jQuery click event on select option doesn't work like if i select myself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to translate my web page automatically using google translator. After the full web page get loaded 3 seconds later i am performing a jQuery click event on select option. The option i want to get selected is get selected by the event but no translation is happening. But if i select on my own translation works on my page.

Here is my code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Mi nombre!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>



<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

 setTimeout(function(){ 

  $('.goog-te-combo').val("bn").click();

  

 }, 3000);


    //$('.goog-te-combo').val("bn").click();
});
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not clicking the element.  Add .click() on the select

Answer (score 0):

Try $('.goog-te-combo').val("bn").trigger('click')